# Why does moving my script references to the bottom of _SiteLayout.cshtml cause the tabs to no longer work?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, asp.net-webpages

I'm using jQuery-UI tabs in my site. I've got this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

...and it works fine, but when I, as suggested for performance reasons, move that to the bottom of the page (after the html, just above the jQuery "ready" function), it no longer works - my nav links are simply bland ULs.

If this is a performance enhancement to drop the script down to the bottom of the page, how can I do it and still have the UI work as it should?

Comment: are these the only scripts in page? If they are it should work fine. Any errors thrown in console?

Comment: Yep, those are the only scripts.

Comment: Do you have ANY other inline JavaScript aside from the jQuery ready function you already mentioned?

Comment: This question is almost three months old - solved long ago, and I don't even recall exactly how; it may have been malformed html - I think it was. Thanks, though!